# Javascript functions doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 6.0.3. If I keep a javascript code in the `app/assets/javascript/packs/file.js`, and then include it with `javascript_pack_tag()`, the functions in the code doesn't work as expected.

---

For example, I have a BlogApp, with a blog controller.

The `app/assets/javascript/packs/file.js`

```
function notifySend(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
}

function notify(arg) {
    notifySend(arg)
}
```

The `app/views/layouts/blog.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= @page_title %></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>

        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'file', %s(data-turbolinks-track) => 'reload' %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>notify('hello!')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

On opening `localhost:3000/blogs`, I get:

```
ReferenceError: notify is not defined
```

In the browser's console.

---

But if I modify the `file.js`, a bit, like this:

```
function notifySend(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
}

notify = function(arg) {
    notifySend(arg)
}
```

The javascript works fine, and I get "hello!" to the browser's console!

---

So there's a hassle of rewriting the functions.

But for bigger JS files or minified files, that can be time consuming. Every function that is called from the `script` tag in body needs a rewrite.

How do I keep my js code intact (like the example 1), and get it working with rails?

Answer (score 2):

This is because webpacker wraps your imports in functions so that they are not placed in the global scope.

In the second example by omitting the var keyword you are creating an implicit global:

```
function notifySend(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
}

notify = function(arg) {
    notifySend(arg)
}
```

This is regarded as a really bad practice and if you where using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or a linter it would have told you so. If you really want to declare a global do so explicitly:

```
function notifySend(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
}

window.notify = notifySend;
```

But the real solution here is to not use inline script tags or inline handlers and write real maintainable minified javascript instead of making a mess. Javascript does not belong in your views. If your code relies on a bunch of globals you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Isn't there a way to copy-paste a valid js (as the first example in the question), and use functions from the `<script>` tag? That's what we generally do in HTML while calling JS functions. Actually for the sake of simplification, my original `notifySend()` is different than what I have written in the question, the original one does this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvnojxTj5uQ.

In vanilla HTML, I can call those functions as it is from the script tag, but in rails, I needed to rewrite the functions. Is there a better way to put JS files so I don't have to modify anything?

Comment: You really need to start with some javascript basics and learn about scope, event oriented programming and writing event handlers.  Writing crap inline JS like its 2001 is not going to cut it if you actually want to make it as a web dev. Get an actual book instead of learning from bad youtube tutorials.